# Selenium click on elements works only in debug mode

Tags: python, angularjs, testing, selenium

I've created a test that click on an element X.
This element is only revealed after you click on another button,
and those elements are connected with *ng-hide*.

When i try to run my code the click on X element doesn't work.
However, in debug mode or after adding 1 second sleep, it does.

I'm using selenium framework in python, with a remote webdriver with ImplicitlyWait of 10 sec.

Does someone knows the reason for this behavior?

Comment: I think you answered your own question: "after adding 1 second sleep". Sounds like a timing problem.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Siking, this is clearly a timing issue.

The fact is that Selenium is very fast and faster than loading of element.
Sometimes, Selenium requires a pause or a sleep to ensure that an element is present.

I also recommend -especially for asynchronous requests- using **waitForElementPresent** to wait until ajax method is finished.

Comment: Can I configure the WebDriver to explicitly wait a few milliseconds before operating any action?   the rationality is to make this configuration general, instead of singular sleep in the code

Comment: I don t think you can do such a thing. I assume that you can set up the speed of tests cases as Selenium IDE can do but even in that case; even if you set it to the slowest; you will get issues as asynchronous queries execution time can t be estimated. If you have a huge latency issue for instance; all your tests will be wrong.